# Can’t get logging to work in a custom pallet when running unit tests

Tags: rust, logging

I can’t get logging to work in a custom pallet when running unit tests:

```
RUST_LOG=runtime=debug cargo test --features rococo-local -- --nocapture
```

`log::debug!("")` doesn’t work and `println!()` doesn’t compile because of `no-std`. (edited)

The custom pallet is importing the `log` facade:

```
use frame_support::{
    dispatch::{DispatchInfo, DispatchResult, PostDispatchInfo},
    ensure, log,
    pallet_prelude::*,
    traits::IsSubType,
};
```

`Cargo.toml` does not have a log crate but I tried adding `log = "0.4.17"` to `dependencies` and also `dev-dependencies` but that had no effect.  I did not try adding it to both.

I tried `RUST_LOG=debug`, `RUST_LOG=runtime=debug` and `RUST_LOG=test=debug` to no avail.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: The log is **not** in the unit tests.  It’s in the custom pallet `lib.rs` which is being called by the unit test.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Rust question.

`log` is just some sort of "code".

You need a trigger to activate it.

e.g.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/fbddfbd76c60c6fda0024e8a44e82ad776033e4b/frame/merkle-mountain-range/src/tests.rs#L473

Answer (score 0):

Using logging didn't work but this did:

```
sp_std::if_std! {
  println!("debug log");
}
```